# cannot resolve type for all std types

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I had Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed on my system.

I uninstalled it and installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

since that I get the following errors:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string': No such file or
>   directory
>
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No
>   such file or directory

also the types uint32_t, int32_t, etc. are not recognized.

I installed again Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, but it didn't help :(

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: it is not a matter of code. this is a problem in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by copying the content folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC` from a different computer that had Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.